# Flot JS x-axis time not formatting properly when trying to display dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, flot

Using Flot I am trying to develop a chart where the x-axis displays dates in %M%D format. However when running the following code it just shows up as the epoch time instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/unwo728s/1/

JavaScript code:

```
var data = [ [gd(2016, 12, 3), 1000], [gd(2016, 12, 4), 200], [gd(2016, 12, 5), 3000], [gd(2016, 12, 6), 1000], [gd(2016, 12, 7), 1000], [gd(2016, 12, 8), 1000]];

var dataset = [
    {
        label: "Daily Amount",
        data: data,
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        points: { fillColor: "#FFFFFF", show: true },
        lines: { show: true }
    }
];

var options = {
    xaxes: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%m/%d",
        tickSize: [3, "day"],
        color: "black",        
        axisLabel: "Date",
    }
};

 $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);

 function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
}
```

[image]

How can I change the x-axis to be properly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var options = {
    xaxis: {
```

Also you need to subtract one from your `month´ parameter ([month is zero-based in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unwo728s/2/).